# The cursor changes thickness when reaches last text position

Tags: xamarin, cursor, editor, comments

I am working on a xamarin app and I have a comment text field with the list  of posts.

Every time the cursor reaches the last position of the text field, it protrudes and get thickened.

Comment: Could you provide some sort of example link/code?